# React Router "hijacking" path of static files

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Let's say I have the following setup:

1. React Application at `/`
2. A previously existing application at `/path/to/application`
3. A JPG at `/assets/image.jpg`
4. A static HTML file for use in an iFrame at `/static/index.html`

ReactRouter (react-router-dom) is attempting to resolve all of these scenarios - displaying the Not Found component in example 2, 3 and 4 as they are naturally not configured.

Strangely, this behaviour seems to differ per browser. Safari and Firefox Quantum resolve as expected, but Chrome does not. For example, in the iFrame example, Chrome is displaying a new instance of the entire root React app inside the iFrame, whereas Safari and Firefox are loading the static HTML file contents.

I have tried using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter but with no luck.

Is there a way I can configure my React application to ignore specific child paths, to allow the server a chance to handle this content?

Comment: this isn't default behaviour of react router. can you post your route components? probably missing `exact` or something

Comment: Please post your src/index.js code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @zoosrc Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.